C re-initializing a variable after using strtok
I'm trying to write a function to search in the PATH directories. I used getenv("PATH") to get the path string, then used strtok() to split it.
The second time I call my function it does not reinitialize the path string. it searches only in the first part of the path.
I know that strtok() modifies the original string terminating each token with a \0 . but in my case I don't understand why calling the function again doesn't create a new string with the normal delimiters ":".
Here is my code:
bool str_in_path(char *target, char *result) {
  char *path = getenv("PATH");
  char *token;
  char tokens[10][100];
  int count = 0;
  
  token = strtok(path, ":");
  strcpy(tokens[0], token);
  count++;

  for (int i = 1; token && i < 10; i++) {
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    if (token) {
      strcpy(tokens[i], token);
      count++;
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    struct dirent *entry = NULL
    DIR *dir = opendir(tokens[i]);
    if (dir == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "can't open directory %s\n", tokens[i]);
      continue;
    }   
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      if (!strcmp(target, entry->d_name)) {
        strcpy(result, tokens[i]);
        strcat(result, "/");
        strcat(result, entry->d_name);
        closedir(dir);
        return true;
      }   
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }
  return false;
}

The first time I call the function it behaves as I expect. the second time it searches only the first part of the path. although it calls char *path = getenv("PATH"); to initialize the path string. why is that and how can I solve it.

Even though getenv returns a char* you should treat it as const char*. Don't make changes to it like you do now. The supported way to change it in Posix systems is by using putenv, so start by doing const char *path = getenv("PATH");  and work from there.

man getenv: "The application should not modify the string pointed to by the getenv() function"

Thanks @TedLyngmo I tried copying the path to a new variable and tokenize the new variable, and it works. Thank you!

Thanks @robertklep I'm new to C and I will make sure to look at man pages first next time.

Great that it worked out! If you want, you could provide an answer to your own question to provide future readers finding this question with a working solution.

@MostafaKashwaa, rather than "copying the path to a new variable", good use of strcspn() and strspn() can perform the strtok() without changing the string.

As mentioned in @chux's comment, strcspn() can be used to parse without modifying the source string.
Also consider breaking the function into two functions. One to parse the path and the other to open the directories.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <dirent.h>

char **parse_path ( char *path, char *delimiter) {
    char **tokens = NULL;
    char **tmp = NULL;
    char *token = path;
    char *end = path;
    size_t items = 0;
    size_t span = 0;

    while ( *token) { // not terminating zero
        end += strcspn ( token, delimiter);
        if ( end == token) {
            break;
        }
        // allocate pointers
        if ( NULL == ( tmp = realloc ( tokens, sizeof *tokens * (items + 2)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem realloc tokens\n");
            break;
        }
        tokens = tmp;
        span = end - token;
        // allocate memory to a pointer
        if ( NULL == ( tokens[items] = malloc ( span + 1))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem malloc token[items]\n");
            break;
        }
        memmove ( tokens[items], token, span);
        tokens[items][span] = 0; // zero terminate
        ++items;
        tokens[items] = NULL; // sentenal NULL
        if ( *end) { // not terminating zero
            ++end; // advance past one delimiter
        }
        token = end;
    }

    return tokens;
}

bool str_in_path_tokens ( char **tokens, char *target, char *result) {
    while ( tokens && *tokens) {
        struct dirent *entry = NULL;
        DIR *dir = opendir ( *tokens);
        if ( dir == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't open directory %s\n", *tokens);
            continue;
        }
        while ( ( entry = readdir ( dir)) != NULL) {
            if ( ! strcmp ( target, entry->d_name)) {
                strcpy(result, *tokens);
                strcat(result, "/");
                strcat(result, entry->d_name);
                closedir(dir);
                return true;
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
        ++tokens;
    }
    return false;
}

void show_path_tokens ( char **tokens) {
    while ( tokens && *tokens) {
        printf ( "%s\n", *tokens);
        ++tokens;
    }
}

void free_path_tokens ( char **tokens) {
    while ( tokens && *tokens) {
        free ( *tokens);
        ++tokens;
    }
}

int main ( void) {
    char *path = getenv ( "PATH");
    char **pathtokens = NULL;

    printf ( "%s\n", path);

    pathtokens = parse_path ( path, ":");
    show_path_tokens ( pathtokens);

    // call
    // str_in_path_tokens ( pathtokens, target, result);
    // as needed with various targets and results
    // no need to reparse the path

    free_path_tokens ( pathtokens);
    free ( pathtokens);
}


What is the advantage of using this method over copying the path and manipulate it with strtok?

As the requirements get more complicated, I found that this is the proper way. strtok is very limiting. thanks @xing

As @TedLyngmo and @robertklep pointed in their comments, the string returned by getenv() function shouldn't be changed by the application. So, the problem was solved by just copying the returned string into a new string and tokenizing the new one, leaving the original string untouched.
Here is the new working code refactored as @xing suggested in his answer to keep parsing and searching logic separated.
bool tokenize(char *str, char tokens[][100], int max_tokens, int *count, const char *delimiter) {
  char *token;                                                                   
  int num_tokens = 0;                                                            
  token = strtok(str, delimiter);                                                
  if (!token)                                                                    
    return false;                                                                
  strcpy(tokens[0], token);                                                      
  num_tokens++;                                                                  
  for (int i = 1; token && i < max_tokens; i++) {                                        
    token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);                                             
    if(token) {                                                                  
      strcpy(tokens[i], token);                                                  
      num_tokens++;                                                              
    }                                                                            
  }                                                                              
  *count = num_tokens;                                                           
  return true;                                                                   
}          

bool str_in_path(char *target, char *result) {
  const char *path = getenv("PATH");
  char path_copy[strlen(path) + 1];
  strcpy(path_copy, path);  // copying the path to avoid manipulating the original string returned by getenv()
  char dirs[20][100] = {};
  int num_dirs;
  tokenize(path_copy, dirs, 20, &num_dirs, ":"); // tokenizing the copied path instead of the original one.

  for (int i = 0; i < num_dirs; i++) {
    struct dirent *entry = NULL;
    DIR *dir = opendir(dirs[i]);
    if (dir == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "can't open directory %s\n", dirs[i]);
      continue;
    }                                                                                                                                                              
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
      if (!strcmp(target, entry->d_name)) {
        strcpy(result, dirs[i]);
        strcat(result, "/");
        strcat(result, entry->d_name);
        closedir(dir);
        return true;
      }
    }
    closedir(dir);
  }
  return false;
}



char path_copy[strlen(path)]; strcpy(path_copy, path); is wrong. path_copy does not have enough space to hold the final NUL terminator. The simplest fix is to change it to path_copy[strlen(path)+1]. Also note that VLA may not be portable but that may or may not be a real concern for you.

Thanks @WeijunZhou I've just updated the code to account for the NULL terminator. Coming from higher level languages, I'm still wrapping my mind around c strings, arrays in the stack and pointers.

You should not mess with the string pointed to by the getenv() function, as said here in comments and answers.
Just copy the string to another place and you should be ok.
An alternative could be write code to parse the PATH string and get the folders using just C code with no library functions as tokenizers.
Consider a function like
        char* get_next_dir(const char read_env);

that returns a string with the next folder in PATH or NULL. read_env can be set to 1 to force reading PATH again if needed in the same run.
As an use case, consider a function like
int parse_path(void)
{
    char* folder = get_next_dir(READ_PATH);
    while (folder != NULL)
    {
        printf("next folder: \"%s\"\n", folder);
        free(folder);
        folder = get_next_dir(0);
    }
    free(folder);
    printf("End of list!\n\n");
    return 0;
}

Since get_next_folder returns the next folder in PATH it is trivial to scan them: just change the loop above and call you scanner.
Here is a possible implementation for get_next_dir, that seems to work under Windows and Linux
char* get_next_dir(const char read_env)
{
    static int   first     = 1;
    static char* env       = NULL;
    static char* next      = NULL;
    static char* var_start = NULL;

#ifdef __linux
    const char delim = ':';  
#else
    const char delim = ';';  // Windows
#endif  // __linux

    unsigned var_size = 0;
    char*    this_var = NULL;

    // get full PATH string
    if ((first != 0) || (read_env != 0))
    {
        first = 0;
        env   = getenv("PATH");
        if (env == NULL) return NULL;
        next      = env;
        var_start = env;
    };

    // get next folder
    while (*next != 0)
    {
        if (*next != delim)
        {
            ++var_size;
            ++next;
        }
        else
        {
            this_var = malloc(1 + var_size);
            memcpy(this_var, var_start, var_size);
            *(this_var + var_size) = 0;
            var_start              = next + 1;
            ++next;
            return this_var;
        }
    };  // while

    // at end of PATH list
    first = 0;
    if (var_size != 0)
    {
        // return last folder in PATH
        this_var = malloc(1 + var_size);
        memcpy(this_var, var_start, var_size);
        *(this_var + var_size) = 0;
        return this_var;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}

A complete test program
#define READ_PATH 1
#define DO_NOT_READ_PATH 1

#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* get_next_dir(const char);
int   parse_path(void);

int main(void)
{
    parse_path();
    parse_path();
    return 0;
}

char* get_next_dir(const char read_env)
{
    static int   first     = 1;
    static char* env       = NULL;
    static char* next      = NULL;
    static char* var_start = NULL;

#ifdef __linux
    const char delim = ':';  // limux
#else
    const char delim = ';';  // Windows
#endif  // __linux

    unsigned var_size = 0;
    char*    this_var = NULL;

    // get full PATH string
    if ((first != 0) || (read_env != 0))
    {
        first = 0;
        env   = getenv("PATH");
        if (env == NULL) return NULL;
        next      = env;
        var_start = env;
    };

    // get next folder
    while (*next != 0)
    {
        if (*next != delim)
        {
            ++var_size;
            ++next;
        }
        else
        {
            this_var = malloc(1 + var_size);
            memcpy(this_var, var_start, var_size);
            *(this_var + var_size) = 0;
            var_start              = next + 1;
            ++next;
            return this_var;
        }
    };  // while

    // at end of PATH list
    first = 0;
    if (var_size != 0)
    {
        // return last folder in PATH
        this_var = malloc(1 + var_size);
        memcpy(this_var, var_start, var_size);
        *(this_var + var_size) = 0;
        return this_var;
    }
    else
        return NULL;
}

int parse_path(void)
{
    char* folder = get_next_dir(READ_PATH);
    while (folder != NULL)
    {
        printf("next folder: \"%s\"\n", folder);
        free(folder);
        folder = get_next_dir(0);
    }
    free(folder);
    printf("End of list!\n\n");
    return 0;
}

example output
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\"
next folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\"
next folder: "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"
next folder: "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin"
next folder: "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
next folder: "C:\Users\arfne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
next folder: ""
next folder: "C:\Users\arfne\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"
End of list!

next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\system32"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\"
next folder: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\"
next folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\"
next folder: "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd"
next folder: "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin"
next folder: "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"
next folder: "C:\Users\arfne\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps"
next folder: ""
next folder: "C:\Users\arfne\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin"
End of list!

